# How to interpret SZ and RSS values

Tags: solaris

I am running a ps command on solaris to get SZ and RSS values, here is the sample output

```
USER-PID-%CPU-%MEM-SZ-RSS-TT-S-START- 

root-3-0.1-0.0-0-0-?-S-Feb- 
qacom2-7440-0.0-0.0-3912-3344-pts/7-O-13:25:22- 
root-6589-0.0-0.15985621000-?-S-Feb-08-1309:34-
```

If you see this outpuit, for PID 6589, SZ is '?' and RSS is 'S' what exactly this indicates?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got the output with all the -'s in but you're looking in the wrong columns.   The "?" is in the TT (aka tty) column, and the 'S' is in the 'state' column.

For instance in this line:

```
qacom2-7440-0.0-0.0-3912-3344-pts/7-O-13:25:22-
```

User = qacom2, pid = 7440, %CPU = 0.0, %MEM = 0.0, RSS= 3912, SZ = 3344

In the following line, unfortunately the column sizes seem to have overflowed so that you can't tell where the column boundaries are:

```
root-6589-0.0-0.15985621000-?-S-Feb-08-1309:34-
```

User = root, pid = 6589, %CPU = 0.0, %MEM = 0.1, RSS & SZ run together = 5985621000

Comment: Is there anyway I can get SZ and RSS values without overlapping? I am running command "/usr/ucb/ps auxww"

Comment: `/usr/bin/ps` provides -o flags to let you specify the exact output you want.

Answer (score 0):

SZ is the total size of the process address space.
RSS is the resident size (the size of the part of the address space that's held in memory) of the process address space.

source : http://oreilly.com/catalog/spt2/chapter/ch04.html
section: Examining Memory Usage of Processes